# mongodb database connection to my database

Tags: mongodb

I connect to mongodb database like this

```
bin]$ ./mongo --host XXXXX-2.XXXXXXX-XXXX.1234.test.com
Connecting to test
mongo>use my_database
```

How do I connect to my_database directly instead of the default ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Omit `--host` and append `/<dbname>` to the host name to provide a "db address":

```
bin]$ ./mongo XXXXX-2.XXXXXXX-XXXX.1234.test.com/my_database
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply Johnny. Actually I was trying to do the mongo export and was trying to resolve the first part of the connection. Could you help me get this command straight     . bin]$ ./mongoexport --host  XXXXX-2.XXXXXXX-XXXX.1234.test.com -db my_database -c dv_locations -f "_id" --csv>driverlocs.csv
Error parsing command line: too many positional options

Comment: @upagna Go ahead and post that separately as it's a different question.